# How to remove Initial rows in a dataframe in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have 4 dataframes with weekly sales values for a year for 4 products. Some of the initial rows are 0 as no sales. there are some other 0 values as well in between the weeks.
I want to remove those initial 0 values, keeping the in between 0s.

For example

```
Week Sales(prod 1)           
1       0
2       0
3       100
4       120
5       55
6       0
7       60.

Week Sales(prod 2)           
1       0
2       0
3       0
4       120
5       0
6       30
7       60.
```

I want to remove row 1,2 from 1st table and 1,2,3 frm 2nd.

Comment: What have you tried so far ? You need to find the index of the row where you want to slice and then slice the dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few Assumption based on your example dataframe:

- DataFrame is created using pandas
- week always start with 1
- will remove all the starting weeks only which are having 0 sales

Solution:

Python libraries Required
 - pandas, more_itertools

Example DataFrame (df):

```
Week Sales         
1       0
2       0
3       0
4       120
5       0
6       30
7       60
```

Python Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import more_itertools as mit

filter_col = 'Sales'
filter_val = 0

##function which returns the index to be removed
def return_initial_week_index_with_zero_sales(df,filter_col,filter_val):
    index_wzs = [False]
    if df[filter_col].iloc[1]==filter_val:
        index_list = df[df[filter_col]==filter_val].index.tolist()
        index_wzs = [list(group) for group in mit.consecutive_groups(index_list)]
    else:
        pass
    return index_wzs[0]

##calling above function and removing index from the dataframe
df = df.set_index('Week')
weeks_to_be_removed = return_initial_week_index_with_zero_sales(df,filter_col,filter_val)
if weeks_to_be_removed:
    print('Initial weeks with 0 sales are {}'.format(weeks_to_be_removed))
    df = df.drop(index=weeks_to_be_removed)
else:
    print('No initial week has 0 sales')

df.reset_index(inplace=True)
Result:df
Week Sales
4    120
5    55
6    0
7    60
```

I hope it helps, you can modify the function as per your requirement.